# Problem with Integration of an Existing Android Library When Building an Android Library

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, integration, libraries

I need to build an Android library for use inside a Unity project. There's nothing different about the build process itself and I managed to build a simple plugin library I can use and I can see commands going in and information coming out.

But now I need to include an external library. I know the library works because I have a demo project, an app, that runs on the required device and does what it's supposed to do. But the instructions to integrate it into a project assume that it is an app and so, do not make much sense in my case.

I have scrolled through a dozen manuals about integrating android libraries but none of them seem to work. I would appreciate a set of instructions about how to integrate an external library in an android project, considering the project is, itself, a library, with respect to the latest Android Studio and build tools.

Comment: What type is your external library mean jar file or dependancy you what integrate?

Comment: What I have is an AAR file.